# Strongly linking two pages together using URL Nonces (with MD5 hash). Any other way to do this?

Tags: url, hash, linked-list, md5, nonce

So, I'm doing a project where there are two pages, page_1 and page_2, where page_2 will ONLY load if the referrer was page_1.

I ended up using URL Nonces from: http://fullthrottledevelopment.com/php-nonce-library, to build this: http://chrisbrittain.com/strong_links/page_1.php

Here is my post explain it: http://chrisbrittain.com/strongly-linking-pages-together-via-url-nonces/

The overall goal here is that both pages be public facing on the net. Page 2 has "secret" data which I want another person to see, but I don't want to have that person log into anything.

So instead, I want to just email him a link and that link will take him to the "secret page"...No one else but the person with the link whom i emailed should have access to the page.

The solution basically uses a nonce handshake between two pages. The nonce is passed as a GET variable, and on page 2, a MD5 hash is computed using the GET passed nonce and a secret string that is the same on page 1 and 2.

QUESTIONS!!! (sorry, I'm being so long winded.)

1. Is there a better industry standard way of doing this?
2. The only real weakness I can see in this implementation is brute force URL checking (which I believe could be stopped by fail2ban, or other methods.)....are there any other obvi design flaws?
3. I know the MD5 hash is now considered bad, but in this implementation I think its safe, since my assumption is that the only way to beat the system here is to Brute Force URL check (which as said could be stopped as a DDoS attack).

Anyways...thank you for reading, any comments/criticism would be great.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to securely control access to page 2 unless you trust the person. The amount of access control you need depends on who you TRUST or what actions you trust them NOT to do.

If you cannot trust the person who you give access to, then if they share the link, anybody can access the page.

If you can trust the person you give access to, then a secret url is enough. That is, if you name page2 to be some secret filename, then there is little else to do, except ensure that your web-server does not have an index.html page where all pages a listed.

If page2 is dynamic, and/or it must be at that filename, you can simply use a secret querystring, eg: `page2.html?secret=assdfadg`. In this case, the secret will be like a password.

Obviously, the above two cases mean that the person could VERY easily share the link. People might be less inclined to share the link if you give them a password.

Ways you could prevent public access to page2 with just simple sharing of a link (accidentally), is to:

- use a password
- check HTTP_REFERER (make sure it is from page1)

However, if you make sure the HTTP_REFERER is from page1, sharing a link to page1 would just as easily allow public access to page2. Also, the HTTP_REFERER is easy to spoof.

---

### Summary

You cannot secure access unless you trust the person you give access to. And if you trust them, then a very simple solution will suffice.

Comment: ^^^awesome reply. just the kinda input i was looking for. Thank you.